# What are the benefits/drawbacks of armor tiers?

Tags: horizon-zero-dawn

The game has what appears to be three tiers of armor; Light (green), Medium (blue), and Heavy (purple). As far as I can tell, the only differences between the tiers are their stats, with stats increasing with each tier. However, are there any other drawbacks/benefits to using higher tiers? Will heavy armor make you move or react more slowly?

This isn't clearly explained anywhere in game, at least as far as I have discovered.

Comment: The colours actually correspond to Uncommon, Rare and Very Rare items, respectively (the rarity is shown somewhere on the right when selecting an item, and this doesn't apply just to outfits but all items). I'm not very far into the game yet, but as far as I can tell Light/Medium/Heavy are just used to give the outfits in these three tiers more flavourful names.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, Light, Medium, and Heavy don't actually correspond to weight (that would just make too much sense, wouldn't it?). Rather, they describe how good they are at what their specialty is.

That is, Light will give the least amount of boost, Medium will give more, but Heavy will give the most. There are no drawbacks from using Heavy over Light (even for the stealth armor...).

[The posts in this thread](https://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/168644-horizon-zero-dawn/75065616) describes it quite well:

> The heavier they are, the better they are at what they do. Armor weight doesn't actually affect you. It's just a straight upgrade to their particular stats.
>
> For example, the silent hunter heavy armor improves your stealth more than the medium, which improves it more than the light.
>
> Edit: heavier armors usually have more mod slots than their light counterparts as well.
>
> Also, from a cosmetic standpoint, the heavier versions usually have a few extra pieces attached.

A more detailed guide on what armor ranks/stats mean can be found [here](http://www.gameskinny.com/vqdht/horizon-zero-dawn-guide-armor-stats-and-what-they-mean) if you want additional information.

Comment: That will do it. I find it odd that they named things Light, Medium, and Heavy, since the assumption is typically the weight of those armors would have drawbacks to movement and mobility and the like, but ah well.

Comment: @Kaizerwolf yeah, I was under that impression until I looked at the stealth armor and was like "yup heavy stealth armor +10 stealth ok"

Comment: FYI, I was concerned the heavier clothing was slowing me down, so I personally ran some sprinting time trials and found there was no speed difference between Aloy's original outfit and one of the "Heavy" armors.

Comment: @Kaizerwolf I would never assume this. In some games, heavier equipment can make you slower, but many games lack a weight mechanic and still use "heavy" and "light" to distinguish armor types. They have a meaning besides weight—they also describe how _effective_ the armor is.